# java - volatile semantics in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, concurrenthashmap, java-memory-model

In `ConcurrentHashMap` of JDK 8, the methods `tabAt` and `setTabAt` are used to provide volatile read/write of the first element of bins in `Node<K,V>[] table`. However, the authors comments that:

> Note that calls to `setTabAt` always occur within locked regions, and so in principle require only release ordering, not full volatile semantics, but are currently coded as volatile writes to be conservative.

I wonder if *release ordering* here means the happens-before relationship (an unlock of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock of that same monitor) guaranteed by `synchronized`. And if so, why `setTabAt` is considered to be *conservative*, but not mandatory, given that the calls to `tabAt` exist not only inside, but also outside `synchronized` blocks? For example:

```java
    /** Implementation for put and putIfAbsent */
    final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
        //...
        for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {
            Node<K,V> f; int n, i, fh;
            if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
                tab = initTable();
            // -> tabAt called here, outside the synchronized block
            else if ((f = tabAt(tab, i = (n - 1) & hash)) == null) {
                if (casTabAt(tab, i, null,
                             new Node<K,V>(hash, key, value, null)))
                    break;                   // no lock when adding to empty bin
            }
            else if ((fh = f.hash) == MOVED)
                tab = helpTransfer(tab, f);
            else {
                V oldVal = null;
                synchronized (f) {
                    // -> tabAt called here, inside the synchronized block
                    if (tabAt(tab, i) == f) {
                        // do insertion...
                    }
                }
            }        
        }
    }
```

Another question is that in the code above, is the call to `tabAt` inside the `synchronized` block necessary? In my understanding, the monitor lock already takes care of the memory visibility between threads, for example:

1. Suppose that there's only one element in the bin, say Node-0
2. Thread-A wants to insert Node-1 in the bin, right after Node-0 it founds by calling `tabAt` outside the `synchronized` block
3. But before Thread-A can lock on Node-0, Thread-B locks Node-0 and deletes it (by calling `setTabAt`)
4. Thread-A acquires the lock of Node-0 after Thread-B has released the lock
5. As the happens-before relationship between Thread-A and Thread-B is guaranteed by the monitor lock, in this case, it seems to me that there's no need to call `tabAt` (which in turn calls `Unsafe.getObjectVolatile`) to access and re-check the element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java-8, that method you mention is defined as:

```
static final <K,V> void setTabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i, Node<K,V> v) {
    U.putObjectVolatile(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE, v);
}
```

In jdk-13, for example, it is already a `release`:

```
static final <K,V> void setTabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i, Node<K,V> v) {
    U.putReferenceRelease(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE, v);
}
```

And, as far as I understand, is supposed to work in conjunction with :

```
static final <K,V> Node<K,V> tabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i) {
    return (Node<K,V>)U.getReferenceAcquire(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE);
}
```

So you can think as `setTabAt` as `set release` and `tabAt` as `get acquire`.

`release` here means [release/acquire semantics](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/), which I sort of talked about in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119169/what-are-memory-fences-used-for-in-java/60130907#60130907). The point is that `volatile` writes do "too much" for some cases (sequential consistency), like the one here.

There is comment in source code (of jdk-13) that says ( about `putReferenceRelease` including) that this is a "weak(er) volatile":

> Versions of putReferenceVolatile... that do not guarantee immediate visibility of the store to other threads...

The `synchronized` part only gives memory visibility guarantees when the *reading* thread uses the same lock too; otherwise all bets are off. It seems this is the part that you are missing. [Here is a more descriptive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235213/thread-has-its-own-copy-of-data/61239326#61239326) that explain how the `synchronized` part can be badly broken.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have spent many days trying to fully understand the difference between volatile semantics and release/acquire semantics according to the article links you provide... Finally I came into [this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering) which I think is clearest for me.

Comment: According to the article mentioned above, Sequentially-consistent ordering "not only order memory the same way as release/acquire ordering but also establish *a single total modification order* of all atomic operations that are so tagged... Sequential ordering may be necessary for *multiple producer-multiple consumer* situations where all consumers must observe the actions of all producers occurring in the same order." But I wonder if `volatile` in Java also guarantees this sort of modification order? Thanks!

Comment: @yangty89 yes, java `volatile` does offer sequential consistency. [Here is more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873873/what-does-subsequent-read-mean-in-the-context-of-volatile-variables)